# Streaming from 'rtmpsrc' doesn't require rtph264depay or h264parse

Tags: gstreamer

Does anyone know why streaming RTMP with `rtmpsrc` doesn't require `rtph264depay` or `h264parse` in the pipeline? The below pipeline works just fine:

`gst-launch-1.0 rtmpsrc location=rtmp://ip/test ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! autovideosink`

And this pipeline does not:

`gst-launch-1.0 rtmpsrc location=rtmp://ip/test ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! autovideosink`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rtph264depay` is for parsing RTP data. You are dealing with RTMP. Those to have absolute nothing in common. You re kinda lucky you don't need a parser as your decoder undestands the data as it comes from RTMP. Having the parser there won't hurt.